# Limit the Kubernetes service account access specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts

I created a service account that contains the default cluster role "view" which makes it can access all of our resources with view permission.

But I would like to add a limitation so that this service account can't access one of our namespace.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Br,

Tim

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes has only two permission scopes: Cluster(`ClusterRole`) or Namespace(`Role`) and no way to limit or exclude a `ClusterRole` to specific namespaces. If you want to restrict your ServiceAccount to specific namespaces you cannot use a `ClusterRole` but must use a `Role` in every namespace the ServiceAccount should have access in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, when you use a `Role`, you need to specify the `namespace` on your `RoleBinding`. For example:

```
$ kubectl create rolebinding my-binding --role=myrole --user=myuser --namespace=mynamespace
```